# Edition of Power BI Report Server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi-report-server

We have faced an issue where the Dev team is not able to view their reports. The installations were all done by them and we had to jump to see what is wrong. We doubt they installed the Evaluation version and the 180 days are over. The error states thats the issue however, we still want to check the edition installed.

We were able to find the Version from registry which was Version 1.4.6969.7395 (Build 15.0.1102.235)

How to find the edition of Power BI Report Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Report Server Configuration Manager, you should be able to see the edition on the first screen that pops up as indicated below.

[image: Power BI Edition]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. For some reasons the dev team could'nt identify it from there and the trial period had expired. Thanks n cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you referring to the release? Like "August Release" or  "January Release"?

You can find them on the changelogs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/changelog

In your case, that's the January Release.